# override IsEnabled property for Custom Control DualButton to set Visibility

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I am working on WPF and have little knowledge of XAML customly created controls.
I have a custom control name 'DualButton' as follows :

```
<Controls:DualButton x:Name="StandardConferenceCancelButton"
                                             Width="90"
                                             Height="25"
                                             Margin="2"
                                             LeftButtonCommand="{Binding StandardModeConnectCommand}"
                                             RightButtonCommand="{Binding ConferenceCancelCommand}"
                                             >
                            <AccessText HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static I18N:TelephonyRegionViewRes.Standard}" />
                        </Controls:DualButton>
```

its 2 dependancy properties 'LeftButtonCommand' and 'RightButtonCommand'binds two different ICommands.
I want to set Visibility of this button to CanExecute of LeftButtonCommand so that when LeftButtonCommandCanExecute() returns true, that time only button gets visible.
I took dependancyProperty 'IsEnabled' what further I need to do in this

Comment: If CanExecute method of LeftButtonDownCommand returns false, did your button gets disabled?

Comment: No. its not. and thats what I want actually. I can post template used for 'DualButton' if you want.

Comment: Yes, please post the template. The crux of the issue is probably there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's late, but might help others...

1. In your DataContext, create a property like `IsVisible` that returns

   ```
   StandardModeConnectCommand.CanExecute()
   ```
2. In your window or user control, add the resource

   ```
     <Window.Resources>
       <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
     </Window.Resources>
   ```
3. In your dual button, after or before the commands, add:

   ```
      Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
   ```
4. Finally, in the places where the returned value of CanEecute is likely to change, add in your datacontext a

   ```
   NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVIsible));
   ```

You should be on track with this.